# Check if nginx config test is sucessfull as condition for bash if

Tags: bash, nginx

I want to check the validity of my nginx configuration using `nginx -t` using it as a condition for a bash script.

```
if [[ $(nginx -t) = *"successful"* ]]; then 
echo "success"; 
else 
echo "failure"; 
fi
```

While the output of `nginx -t`contains `successful`, bash prints `failure` regardless. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I don't want to check by exit code but by string output.

Solution:

````
if [[ $(nginx -t 2>&1) = *"successful"* ]]; then 
echo "success"; 
else 
echo "failure"; 
fi
```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

You are expecting the message to printed on stdout. It is printed on stderr. Redirect stderr to stdout to capture the message.

If you want to capture stderr and stdout of a command and also check it's exit status, do:

```
if out=$(nginx -t 2>&1); do
    echo "success"
else
    echo "failure, because: $out"
fi
```

Comment: Hi, didn't know about stderr. However I do not want to check exit status. I want to campare by content of the output string. Basically just replaced `nginx -t`with `nginx -t 2>&1`

Answer (score 1):

Here is my (working) script to do the same:

```
nginx -t >/dev/null 2>&1
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "success"
else
    echo "failure"
fi
```

Comment: Thanks, while this would work I'd like to not use the exit status of the command, since this could prove problematic further down the line if I want to introduce errror handling since it omits the information of the output.

Comment: `since this could prove problematic further down the line if I want to introduce errror handling` I do not understand. Handling exit status is error handling.

Comment: @IvanShatsky Doing `cmd; if [ $? ...` is an antipattern. Do not do it - if possible do not use `$?`. Just `if nginx -t >/dev/null 2>&1; then ...`

Comment: @KamilCuksaying erro handling means I want to make a few things based on the information of the nginx error string. Some exit code doesn't contain that informationj